# Unable to alert the message by capturing the array value in php using javascript.

Tags: php, soap-client

```
    foreach ($record_sets as $row) {
        $params->Loginname = "a";
        $params->Password = "xxxxxxx";
        $params->studentresult = "<a1><marks>95</marks><grade>A</grade></a1>"; 
        $params->rollid = $row[0];

        $response = $client->Marksofstudent($params);
        $result = $response->Marksresult->SqlXml->any;

        var_dump($result);    

        if (strpos($result, 'error') === false) {
        /* do nothing */
    }  else {
        $array = array(
                    "marks" => $row[0],
                    "Subject"  => $row[1]
                 );
    ?> 
    <script>
    message = 'failure to post for ' + <?php echo $array->$row[0]; ?> + 'reportid and ' + '<?php echo $array->row[1]; ?>' +  'certificatenumber';
    adiha_CreateMessageBox('alert', message);
    </script>
<?php } } ?>
    }
```

I want to prompt the message after execution of the foreach loop and capture those all $row[0] and $row[1] value and alert the message 'Unable to $row[0] and $row[1] combination update'. 
Currently in the above code, i cannot get the $row[0] and $row[1] value.

I want a message like 'Unable to upload marks 1 subject x marks 2 subject y'.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are doing but if you want to use the data you are adding to the array you have to change your code:

```
else {
    $array = array(
        "marks" => $row[0],
        "Subject"  => $row[1]
    );
?> 
<script>
    message = 'failure to post for ' + <?php echo $array['marks']; ?> + 'reportid and ' + '<?php echo $array['Subject']; ?>' +  'certificatenumber';
    adiha_CreateMessageBox('alert', message);
</script>
```

Or use `$row[0]` and `$row[1]` instead if you do not use the array otherwise in your code.

Comment: $roll_id = ''; 
foreach($record_sets as $row) {
    $params->Loginname = "xxx";
    $params->Password = "xxxxxx";
    $params->studentresult = $row[1];  
    $params->rollid = $row[0];

    $response = $client->NCRETS_SubaccountTransfer($params);
    $result = $response->NCRETS_SubaccountTransferResult->SqlXml->any;

    var_dump($result);

    if (strpos($result, 'error') === false) {
        /* do nothing */
    }  else {
        $roll_id = $roll_id . ', ' . $row[1];
    }
}